# Problem on total derivative of bilinear form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, bilinear-form

Let $A $ be an invertible real $ n\times n $ matrix. Define a function $ F\colon\mathbb  R^{n}\times \mathbb R^{n} \to\mathbb R $ by $ F (x,y)=\langle Ax,y\rangle $ where $ \langle x,y\rangle $ denotes the inner product of $x$ and $y$ .let $ DF(x,y) $ denote the derivative of $F$ at (x,y) which is a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^{n}\times \mathbb R^{n}\to \mathbb R $ then

1. If $ x\neq 0 $ then $ DF(x,0)\neq 0 $
2. If $ y\neq 0 $ then $ DF(0,y)\neq 0 $
3. If $ (x,y)\neq 0 $ then $ DF(x,y)\neq 0 $
4. If $ x=0 $ or $ y=0 $ then $ DF(x,y) $=0 $

To determine which options are true  , I use the fact  $ (DF (x,y))(h,k) = f(h,y)+f(x,k) = \langle Ah,y\rangle +\langle Ax,k\rangle  $ . So option 4 is true ,  and   the other 3 options  are not necessarily true,  since it depends on $ (h,k)  $ also.

Am I right ? otherwise please give me some hints.  Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend actually computing the partial derivatives. The total derivative is zero if and only if the partials are

Comment: I didn't understand sir,  will you please explain a little more.

Comment: you can expand the inner product as a polynomial in $x_i$ and $y_i$, where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the components of $x$ and $y$ for $i=1,2,...,n$. Then take the partial derivatives with respect to each variable $x_i,y_i$.

Comment: No need for coordinates, it follows from the formula $DB(x,y)(h,k) = B(x,k)+B(h,y)$ for bilinear maps $B$ (this is a product rule). See duplicate question in link above.

Comment: @ Ivo Terek sir, I saw your  answer,  option 4 is not true in general , but If I take  (h, k)=(0,0) then 1, 2 and 3 are also false I mean 1, 2 and 3 options are not true in general .

Comment: @ mheldman sir,  but sir they didn't define the inner product , but  sir If I use standard inner product,  then yes option 1 , 2 and 3 are true. But  sir  for  arbitrary inner product space what do I do?